# multi-step registration

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am currently using `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin` and `sfDoctrineForkedApplyPlugin` for my user management.

This works well for me and users can register/login etc

The problem comes with the registration part. The `Profile` relation that I have is getting particularly large in terms of fields users are required to fill out on registration.

I was thinking of possibly creating a multistep process, possibly 2 steps.

Step 1 is the main details, such as name, username, password etc
Step 2 is the address and my other fields

I don't want my users to scroll down to fill out 25 fields on a single form

I'm not entirely sure how I'd do this and I cannot find any information regarding carrying out this.

Has anyone ever done this before and If so, could someone point me in the right direction of how I'd do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a form class for every step. When processing the submitted form, save the submitted part to the session if validation passes.

In the end you'll have an array of validated values for every step, just compose your model object out of them, and save the object.

Comment: I've come across an existing implementation using Propel: http://blog.adryjanek.eu/2009/03/24/symfony-12-and-multipage-form-wizard/ I just need to have a look at this and see If I can modify it for Doctrine

Comment: The implementation above which you suggested I should do seems to have worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic way of handling multi-step forms in Symfony:

[How to 'validate' a Symfony form in steps - instead of calling $form->isValid()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545398/how-to-validate-a-symfony-form-in-steps-instead-of-calling-form-isvalid/3552992#3552992)

Comment: Not to worry, I got the code in the link above working for me.